# How to round up or round down decimal places?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I want to suggest a bid for users in a reverse of forward manners.

For reverse:

- 1.23 => 1.20
- 2.35 => 2.30
- 3.59 => 3.50
- 4.99 => 4.90

For forward:

- 1.23 => 1.30
- 2.35 => 2.40
- 3.59 => 3.60
- 4.99 => 5.00

I've tried using `math.floor()` and `math.ceil()`, but it will only round it off to the nearest integer. Can you give me a solution or suggestion for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Math.floor(a*10)/10` and `Math.ceil(a*10)/10` where `a` is the number you want to round.

```js
console.log(Math.floor(1.23*10)/10)
console.log(Math.floor(2.35*10)/10)
console.log(Math.floor(3.59*10)/10)
console.log(Math.floor(4.99*10)/10)
console.log('')
console.log(Math.ceil(1.23*10)/10)
console.log(Math.ceil(2.35*10)/10)
console.log(Math.ceil(3.59*10)/10)
console.log(Math.ceil(4.99*10)/10)
```

If you need the final value as a string in the format X.YY (and not X.Y) you can use `toFixed(2)` (ie `(Math.ceil(1.23*10)/10)).toFixed(2)`)